# Add More than One Custom Sections to App Config C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

I would like to make an app.config that looks like

```
<configuration>

<SQLconneciton>
  <add key=name/>
  <add key= otherStuff/>
</SQLconnection>
<PacConnection>
  <add key=name/>
  <add key= otherStuff/>
</PacConnection>

</configuration>
```

I've read many examples where people make ONE custom section and add stuff, I need to allow the user to add multiple sections, read, delete. I don't really need fancy elements, just simple add and key values. Is section groups worth using or is there something easy I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - there's really nothing stopping you from creating as many custom config sections as you liked!

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- define the config sections (and possibly section groups) you want in your config file -->
  <configSections>
    <section name="SqlConnection" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    <section name="PacConnection" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <!-- "implement" those config sections as defined above -->
  <SqlConnection>
    <add key="abc" value="123" />
  </SqlConnection>
  <PacConnection>
    <add key="abc" value="234" />
  </PacConnection>
</configuration>
```

The `System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler` is the default type to use for a config section that contains `<add key="...." value="....." />` entries (like `<appSettings>`).

To get the values, just use something like this:

```
NameValueCollection sqlConnConfig = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("SqlConnection") as NameValueCollection;
string valueForAbc = sqlConnConfig["abc"];
```

And you can absolutely mix and match existing section handler types as defined by .NET as well as your own custom config sections, if you've defined some of those yourself - just use whatever you need!